# Window.print() scaling of page content?

Tags: javascript, printing, window, border

Hey all I am running into an issue trying to print out an image on a page. I'm using the simple Window.print() method in javascript to get this done however in the print preview the image doesn't maintain its border. I can mess with the margin settings in the print dialog that shows up but I can't ever get the whole border to show up.

Does the method autoscale images or something? I'm not sure why it would change the border setting on that image.

Comment: It's very likely browser, OS and/or printer driver dependent..

Comment: I agree with Mike, the method just calls the browser's print dialog.  Each browser/printer/OS will be setup slightly differently.  Also, note that if you're using CSS there's CSS options to differ the CSS for on screen or for print.  Web programming isn't really best suited to produce materials for print.  Perhaps consider downloadable PDF's if uniform printing is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

The `window.print()` method doesn't autoscale or modify document in any way. Consider adding a Print CSS ([try this tool](http://printstylesheet.com/)) to get this right for the printed format without affecting what's already being displayed on the screen.